# React Router Redirect not firing after history.push used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using react-router-dom and I am trying to push to the browser history using the history object from the `useHistory` hook. The path that I push to should trigger some logic within the router which will force a redirect to another path (which renders some content).

My issue is that the `<Redirect />` does not seem to be doing anything and I'm not 100% sure I know why. I created a [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-example-forked-5k0c0b?file=/src/index.js) to demonstrate the issue that I am having. (Same as code below). You can see the issue if you manually navigate the browser in the codepen to the main route e.g `https://c629mk.csb.app/`, you will see no content load.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect,
  useHistory,
  BrowserRouter,
  useRouteMatch
} from "react-router-dom";

const HomeRouter = () => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();
  const someRouterSpecificLogic = true;
  const initialPath = someRouterSpecificLogic ? "location" : "videos";
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`${path}/location`} render={() => <h1>Location</h1>} />
      <Route path={`${path}/videos`} render={() => <h1>Videos</h1>} />
      <Redirect from={`${path}/`} to={`${path}/${initialPath}`} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

const AboutRouter = () => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`${path}/history`} render={() => <h1>History</h1>} />
      <Route path={`${path}/background`} render={() => <h1>Background</h1>} />
      <Redirect from={`${path}/`} to={`${path}/history`} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

const useSomeAsyncHook = () => {
  const [asyncResult, setAsyncResult] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAsyncResult("someValue");
    }, 300);
  });
  return asyncResult;
};

const AppRouter = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const asycnResult = useSomeAsyncHook();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (asycnResult === "someValue") {
      history.push("/home");
    }
  }, [history, asycnResult]);

  return (
    <>
      <p>There should be other content rendering on this page:</p>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/home" component={HomeRouter} />
        <Route path="/about" component={AboutRouter} />
        <Redirect from="/" to="/home" />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
};
const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppRouter />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

What I think is happening is this:

1. `/` renders triggering the Redirect to `/home`
2. useEffect pushes `/` to the history again
3. Redirect logic does not work the second time around

I am wondering if anyone knows how to force the redirect to happen at 3 again?

Comment: Why are you actively trying to make your code render loop?! I don't know what your endgame is here but if you simply remove the `history.push("/")`  side-effect the redirect from `"/"` to `"/home"` works entirely as expected. What are you trying to accomplish? Also not helping you in your sandbox is using two different versions between `react` and `react-dom` (*they should be on the exact same version*), using `history@5` (*RRDv5 uses `history@4`*), and a super old version of `react-scripts` (*v1 but should probably be on at least v4*).

Comment: Hello, I don't know the solution, but my understanding is that the `Redirect` component is a declarative way to redirecting the user, while the `history.push` is imperative. This different mismatch, what is causing the issue you're facing. `history.push` imperatively adds a new URL, but React doesn't re-render, thus, the declarative `Redirect` doesn't run and redirect the user. It only runs the first because the component is rendering, after that, nothing changes and thus the redirect it's not working. I'm interesting why you want to do such a thing in the first place.

Comment: @DrewReese in my app the redirect is happening in App.js on app load after an api request has completed and pushes the user to the correct place in the app. The Redirect component is rendering inside a particular part of the app further down the component tree so I'm not precisely hardcoding a loop in my app but this example is illustrative of the problem (also I wouldn't expect the example to loop infinitely as the effect would only run once)

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAli ah that is interesting.  My comment above sort of explains the reason that I want to do this. I thought the history.push would cause the component to rerender. Perhaps if I trigger an effect based on history.listen I can force the component tree to rerender?

Comment: So your code example here isn't an accurate representation for what you are really trying to do? Can you provide a more accurate [mcve]?

Comment: @CHeffernan087 Yes, you can force an update/re-render, but that's not the point. If you do, you will just face the same problem as the `useEffect` hook will run again after every history change as you are pushing a new state/entry to the history object, resulting in a loop like @DrewReese mentioned. If you could illustrate what you want to do that led to this situation, it'd be better. Your comment above about what you want to do is kinda vague. Trying to work around the rendering/imperative issue here is not the correct approach.

Comment: I've updated my question above with a new sandbox link that illustrates the problem better. Basically there are different parts of my app and the user is routed based on the result of an api call.

I thought that pushing to the history like this would basically force a "re-run of the routing logic" but I understand now that that is not how React works and I was not triggering the Redirect to re-render. I have a solution now which I will link in a comment below. Open to other suggestions or I can post this as the answer the question otherwise

Comment: A simple enough solution just adding a load state here: 

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-example-forked-l00oo5?file=/src/index.js

The problem was that pushing to the history would not trigger a rerender of the component. This way I am not rendering the routing components until the location is what I want to redirect to per the effect

Comment: I agree my codepen could have been more descriptive. The solution as applied to that codepen would probably look something like this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-example-forked-c629mk?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by adding a loadState to the code. This way the routes / redirect logic only renders after the history.push has taken place.

I was confused because I thought that history.push would update the internal state of browserRouter and trigger a rerender of all child routes/ redirects. This is not the case. In my case history.push did not cause the Redirect component to rerender to it did not trigger another redirect and the user would just see a white screen. Adding a loadstate as shown below resolved the problem for me:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect,
  useHistory,
  BrowserRouter,
  useRouteMatch
} from "react-router-dom";

const HomeRouter = () => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();
  const someRouterSpecificLogic = true;
  const initialPath = someRouterSpecificLogic ? "location" : "videos";
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`${path}/location`} render={() => <h1>Location</h1>} />
      <Route path={`${path}/videos`} render={() => <h1>Videos</h1>} />
      <Redirect from={`${path}/`} to={`${path}/${initialPath}`} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

const AboutRouter = () => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`${path}/history`} render={() => <h1>History</h1>} />
      <Route path={`${path}/background`} render={() => <h1>Background</h1>} />
      <Redirect from={`${path}/`} to={`${path}/history`} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

const useSomeAsyncHook = () => {
  const [asyncResult, setAsyncResult] = useState(false);
  const [asyncResultFetched, setAsyncResultFetched] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAsyncResult("someValue");
      setAsyncResultFetched(true);
    }, 300);
  });
  return { asyncResult, asyncResultFetched };
};

const AppRouter = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { asycnResult, asyncResultFetched } = useSomeAsyncHook();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (asycnResult === "someValue") {
      history.push("/home");
    }
  }, [history, asycnResult]);

  if (!asyncResultFetched) {
    return <h1>Loading...</h1>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>There should be other content rendering on this page:</p>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/home" component={HomeRouter} />
        <Route path="/about" component={AboutRouter} />
        <Redirect from="/" to="/home" />
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
};
const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppRouter />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Thank you to @Abdulrahman Ali and @Drew Reese for their assistance in helping me realise what my issue was in the comments of my question above